# In CSS, how can I combine flexbox and object-position?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Would you have a peak at my CSS problem and see if you can help me with it?  I am quite stuck.  Embarrassingly, three-weeks stuck.

In the code below, without the height, object-fit, and object-position properties, the code does what I want it to do.  It resizes the image when I change the size of the browser window.

If I change it so that only a cropped portion of the image is shown by adding those properties, it does not.  When I change the size of the browser window, the image now does not resize.  Instead, it becomes further cropped.  See [Demo][1] for a visualization of the problem.

Sincerely,

Dante

P.S.: This is for a data science project where the template will be updated with my scientific images when I can get the code to work.

REFERENCES
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6nDm.gif

FULL CODE:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  /* IE10 */
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* IE10 */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column {
  -ms-flex: 14%;
  /* IE10 */
  flex: 14%;
  max-width: 14%;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  object-fit: none;
  object-position: 50% 6%;
}

div.rowlabel1 {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5vw;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="rowlabel1">Test</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div><img src="wedding.jpg" style="width:100%"></div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div><img src="wedding.jpg" style="width:100%"></div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div><img src="wedding.jpg" style="width:100%"></div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div><img src="wedding.jpg" style="width:100%"></div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div><img src="wedding.jpg" style="width:100%"></div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div><img src="wedding.jpg" style="width:100%"></div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="rowlabel1">Test</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div><img src="wedding.jpg" style="width:100%"></div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div><img src="wedding.jpg" style="width:100%"></div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div><img src="wedding.jpg" style="width:100%"></div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div><img src="wedding.jpg" style="width:100%"></div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div><img src="wedding.jpg" style="width:100%"></div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div><img src="wedding.jpg" style="width:100%"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am still mired in this problem, but I changed width: 100% to width: auto, and the problem improved. The images now only become further cropped when the padding shrinks to zero. And only the right side of the images become further cropped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

Changed width: 100% to width: auto

Changed max-width: 14% to max-width: auto

Deleted the wrap stuff in the row class